# Parent DIV is full width while child div is specific width

Tags: css, html

I'm having a hard time to solve how to accomplish this parent div is full `width:100%` with specific `height:500px` then I want the child `DIV` with specific width and height let's just say `width:980px;height = the height of parent DIV` then that parent `DIV` will be divided into **3 columns**. how to accomplish that?

sample image:

[image: sample]

**GREEN :** Parent DIV with full width.

**BLUE:** Child DIV divided into `3 columns`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show us, what you have tried till now??

Comment: `margin: 0px auto;` on an extra `div` wrapping those 3 inner-divs. It will be invisible and only used as a placeholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x6MEX/).

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <div class="grandchildren">
        </div>
        <div class="grandchildren">
        </div>
        <div class="grandchildren">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

style

```
div#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

div#child {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}

div.grandchildren {
     border: 1px solid yellow;
     display: table-cell;
}
```

EDIT: a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/x6MEX/1/) without using `table` styles but using `float` instead

Comment: +1, but why abuse the `table`-styling for this? You would only deceive yourself for the HTML you read besides your stylesheet. You might just aswel do a a `table` with one row. Then you're at least sure that the HTML you're looking at behaves like the elements you declare ;)

Comment: @Kuma Thank you sir! Anyways, I read about **display:table-cell** is not cross browser compatible like IE8??

Comment: @Unknownymous Just remove the `table-cell` and `table` styling and give the grand-children custom widths and use `display: inline-block;` or `float`s and you're done.

Comment: @Kuma BTW, How to make **grandchild** responsive?

Answer (score 2):

I took too long to answer I guess :) here's another jsfiddle, this one's responsive:

http://jsfiddle.net/LmHjU/2/

```
<div class="green_block">
    <ul class="blue_block">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.green_block{
    background: #22B14C;
    width: 100%
}

ul.blue_block{
    background: #00A2E8;
    border: 3px solid #4DBDF3;
    height: 500px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80%; /* or whatever width you need */

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
}

ul.blue_block li{
    border-right: 3px solid #5E8899;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
}

ul.blue_block li:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}
```

Cheers!